# Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to use a ASP.NET(C#) application on a IIS-Server. Everything is working great, i have only one problem. I'm trying to create a CSV-File in the 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bin' directory, but i get the errormessage "Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bin' is denied.".

I tried to give the 'IUSR' and the 'NT-AUTHORITY/networkservice' all rights, but it still doesn't work. I also tried it in an other directory but also doesn't work.

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Thx! Works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the `App_Data` folder for that, **NOT** the `bin` folder:

more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23.aspx

and: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx

Comment: Bin folder is solely for system. use App_data for application data is best, it also safe as well...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the rights to the ASPNET user, that might be the issue.
Also, writing a file at the root of the web-folder, is basically a bad idea.

It's much safer if you put create the files in a folder that is not accessible from the web, and than use a separate page to download the file (I'm guessing that's what you are trying to accomplish), something along [these lines](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/76293.aspx).